# Express and Typescript integration

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, angular

Hi and thanks for taking time to help me.

I recently did a Cron app with Node.JS. I would add a website hosted by the Node.js server with Express. I developped this typescript website in another folder, and when the time came to integrate it into my Node.js server, I've got errors which are theses :

```
shim.min.js       : 1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
zone.js            : 1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Reflect.js         : 1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
system.src.js      : 1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
systemjs.config.js : 8 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
app                : 1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
(index)            : 28 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Evaluating http://localhost/public/app
Error loading http://localhost/public/app
```

Here is my folder organisation

[project_tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQbo0.png)

And here is my index.html and my systemjs.config.js which I think are the problems. You have to know that if I put node_modules in public and in the root, it works. I think it's a path problem.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Cts</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icone.png" id="icone" />

    <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCCGhv7ryot0iu9ufz-BXlZBZxcYhB7q8c">
    </script>
     <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <!--<script async defer src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC6bfdXKHUFQltpGyCgC6cmVBx-gDWvxlM"></script>-->
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="../node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>



    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
     <base href="/" >

  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>  
          <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my systemjs.config.js

```
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   '../node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': '../node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       '../node_modules/rxjs',
    'mapbox-gl':                  '../node_modules/mapbox-gl'

  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },

  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];
  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

I hope you understood my problem, thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that your Express app is not serving static files from `../node_modules` but only from the public folder (which is the right way to do it). That would also explain the `Unexpected token <` errors as Express is sending the `index.html` by default if it is not able to serve a requested file. It would also explain your remark that everything works fine if you put your `node_modules` in your `public` folder.

A possible solution is to serve client-side libraries from a `vendor` folder inside your `public` folder. You can create a task in your gruntfile to copy the vendor files you need automatically. Another solution is to serve all your client-side libraries from CDN. So in your `index.html` this would maybe look like this:

```
<script src="vendor/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.4.1/shim.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That was really helpful ! Thanks for taking the time to answer !

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer solved your problem, you should mark it as the accepted answer for your question.